# Nightwatch cannot take screenshot return is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

I'm using `nightwatch-cucumber` module, which works pretty great,
but I can't save any screenshot in my testing step.

nightwatch.config.js

```
...
test_settings: {
  default: {
    screenshots : {
      enabled : true,
      on_failure : true,
      path: 'screenshots/'
    },
...
```

step.js

```
...
return pageObj
  .submit()
  .waitForElementVisible('@status')
  .getText('@status')
  .saveScreenshot('./screenshots')
  .expect.element('@status').text.to.contain(status);
...
```

console error
`TypeError: pageObj.submit(...).waitForElementVisible(...).getText(...).saveScreenshot is not a function`

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one in the command section. In page object file.

```
const commands = {
    saveScreenshot(filePath) {
        this.api.saveScreenshot(filePath);
        return this;
    }

    module.exports = {
        url: 'url',
        commands: [commands],
        elements: {
            .......
        }
    };
}
```